# What is a United Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

If a word has a certain property, it is a United Word.
Use the examples below to find the property:

| United | not-united |
| --- | --- |
| ALMOND | WALNUT |
| ALPACA | LLAMA |
| CALAMARI | SQUID |
| COCA COLA | PEPSI COLA |
| CONCORDE | JUMBO JET |
| COOK | CHEF |
| DECADE | CENTURY |
| FLAK | FIRE |
| FLORAL | FLOWERY |
| INKY | PENCIL |
| INLAND | COASTAL |
| MAINLAND | OFFSHORE |
| MEMORIAL | MONUMENT |
| NECTAR | AMBROSIA |
| RIMS | TYRES |
| SCALAR | VECTOR |

CSV version:

```
United,not-united
ALMOND,WALNUT
ALPACA,LLAMA
CALAMARI,SQUID
COCA COLA,PEPSI COLA
CONCORDE,JUMBO JET
COOK,CHEF
DECADE,CENTURY
FLAK,FIRE
FLORAL,FLOWERY
INKY,PENCIL
INLAND,COASTAL
MAINLAND,OFFSHORE
MEMORIAL,MONUMENT
NECTAR,AMBROSIA
RIMS,TYRES
SCALAR,VECTOR
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think a United Word (tm) is one which

> is composed entirely of standard two-letter abbreviations for names of states of the US.

Comment: Dang it-you guys are too good!I thought this would be a bit trickier, but it was cracked almost straight away...if you're that good check out my other puzzle where Kitty is still languishing in her mission....

Comment: The thing that jumped out at me was that all the United Words were of even length. That suggested looking at pairs of letters, and then boom :-).