# What is a Unionized Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>*In the spirit of the What is a [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion)/[Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463), a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) puzzles.*</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a ***Unionized Word™***.
Use the examples below to find the rule.

| Unionized Words™ | Not Unionized Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| Akin | Alike |
| Aria | Solo |
| Cook | Bake |
| Dewy | Vernal |
| Hind | Fore |
| Ilks | Kinds |
| Inky | Dark |
| Many | Most |
| Pact | Treaty |
| Scut | Tail |
| Wail | Outcry |
| Wide | Narrow |
| Arcane | Ordinary |
| Florid | Ornate |
| Gamine | Tomboy |
| Scrims | Curtains |
| Vandal | Looter |
| Coalmine | Goldmine |
| Memorial | Gravestone |
| Marineland | Seaworld |

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Unionized Words™,Not Unionized Words™
Akin,Alike
Aria,Solo
Cook,Bake
Dewy,Vernal
Hind,Fore
Ilks,Kinds
Inky,Dark
Many,Most
Pact,Treaty
Scut,Tail
Wail,Outcry
Wide,Narrow
Arcane,Ordinary
Florid,Ornate
Gamine,Tomboy
Scrims,Curtains
Vandal,Looter
Coalmine,Goldmine
Memorial,Gravestone
Marineland,Seaworld
```

The puzzle satisfies the series' inbuilt assumption, that each word can be tested for whether it is a Unionized Word™ without relying on the other words.
These are not the only examples of Unionized Words™; many more exist.

**What is the special rule these words conform to?**

Comment: Plumbers and physicists?

Comment: I was hoping we were supposed to read it as "un-ionized word" and it was going to be something about positive/negative.

Comment: Related (spoilerifically): [The Madman's Speech](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/16513/5373)

Comment: I'm intrigued by some of the markdown in this post, especially `rubio.2017.02.04` ...

Comment: @randal'thor It's a template, available for others to use if they wish. that bit in particular is a version stamp that also happens to serve a purpose in the formatting; if someone is using the template they can check that version against whatever my latest posting of this type used, and update their local copy if it's been updated.

Comment: @Rubio So it's basically a trap street ;-) You've given yourself an easy way to check if anybody is using your formatting.

Comment: @randal'thor The code's unique enough that I can find it trivially even without the versioning, if that was the goal. :)

Comment: Hmm, duplicate of https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/49065/what-is-a-united-word ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

A Unionized Word™ is a word ...

> ... that is made up wholly of [abbreviations of US states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_states_and_territories_of_the_United_States). Unionized refers to the Union, i.e. the United States as in the State of the Union address.

My first thought was ...

> ... that the first letter pair was an abbreviation of a state, but that gave me false positives for the Not Unionized Words™ Alike, Most Ordinary and Ornate. Florid and Marineland are good hints, becuse they are close enough to Florida and Maryland.

Evidence section for Unionized Words:

> **AK·IN** — Alaska · Indiana
>  **AR·IA** — Arkansas · Iowa
>  **CO·OK** — Colorado · Oklahoma
>  **DE·WY** — Delaware · Wyoming
>  **HI·ND** — Hawaii · North Dakota
>  **IL·KS** — Illinois · Kansas
>  **IN·KY** — Indiana · Kentucky
>  **MA·NY** — Massachusetts · New York
>  **PA·CT** — Pennsylvania · Connecticut
>  **SC·UT** — South Carolina · Utah
>  **WA·IL** — Washington · Illinois
>  **WI·DE** — Wisconsin · Delaware
>  **AR·CA·NE** — Arkansas · California · Nebraska
>  **FL·OR·ID** — Florida · Oregon · Idaho
>  **GA·MI·NE** — Georgia · Michigan · Nebraska
>  **SC·RI·MS** — South Carolina · Rhode Island · Mississippi
>  **VA·ND·AL** — Virginia · North Dakota · Alabama
>  **CO·AL·MI·NE** — Colorado · Alabama · Michigan · Nebraska
>  **ME·MO·RI·AL** — Maine · Missouri · Rhode Island · Alabama
>  **MA·RI·NE·LA·ND** — Massachusetts · Rhode Island · Nebraska · Louisiana · North Dakota

Comment: *IMO* you should show what each one should be, to help people understand the more difficult ones.

Comment: Yeah,good idea. I've added it.

Comment: Nicely done and perfectly explained